# ical html feed has raw code visible at the top of grid

Tags: civievent

The html page for my CiviCRM ical events feed has a mess of code visible at the top of the events grid.  The only similar problem I can find with a Google search is a bug report: "the Order Rows widget is broken again" but I can't find a solution.  My site is running on an AWS instance with Amazon Linux and the Joomla 3.6.2 framework and CiviCRM 4.7.11

Here is a link to the broken page:  https://greatconjunction.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=0&html=1

Thank you for your help!